# my --webkit-background-clip and --webkit-text-fill-color is not working

Tags: html, css, webkit

```
#navbar_logo {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  --webkit-background-clip: text;
  --moz-background-clip: text;
  --webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; i do not know why it is not working
  --moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

i do not know why it is not working i am doing all what other person is doing on youtube

Comment: I guess the flex is the problem. You need to apply this logic to the flex item not the flex container

Answer (score 0):

I think I was following the same tutorial. It looks silly but changing `background-image` to `background` and removing `to top` inside the linear gradient worked for me.